# Video does not want to upload on YouTube

Tags: youtube, upload

I´m trying to upload a video to YouTube, but it is not working. I´ve uploaded videos in the past, but have not been able to upload this video yet.

What happens, is, I select the video, but it never shows the progress bar and I can keep selecting videos.

I´ve tried it so far on Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. Same results on every browser. I also tried the `basic´ uploader, but when I pressed the button to select a video, it does not open an explorer window.

My internet speeds: Down: 11.79 Mb/s, Up: 0.85 Mb/s

O/S: Windows 7 64 Bit

Video format: Sony AVC (MP4, 720p, 29.9fps)
Video size: 234MB

Comment: What is the length of the video?

Comment: @Dez 6:01 minutes

Comment: Have you tried to delete the video you attempted to upload from your [video manager](http://www.youtube.com/my_videos?feature=mhee) and then re-upload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found the YouTube discussion forums, and apparently there are server-side issues with YouTube at the moment. YouTube partner / monetizing accounts get an old uploader that doesn't display the upload itself, although it still does. A workaround is select the video, keep your tab open, open new tab, go to YouTube video manager, and you'll see your video processing there.